# Git shows changes and new files after copying repo from one computer to another

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-diff

I have Git repository on server A (Windows). TortoiseGit shows green on folder. When trying git commit, there are no changes, there is nothing to commit. Everything is OK.

Now I copied this repository to different server B (Windows) using Total Commander. ToroiseGit suddenly started to show red flag on repository folder. When trying git commit, there are several changes in existing files and several new not versioned files. BUT current content of "changed" files and "not versioned" files is exactly the same like in Git repository on private Git server.

I hope my description is sufficient.

What is the solution for this problem?

What I tried:

- git pull - not working because Git claims there are changed files and that "not versioned" files would be overwritten
- git fetch - current repository from Git server was fetched but nothing changed in local repository

Comment: Use the command line, not TortoiseGit, to inspect things, so as to rule out any bugs in TortoiseGit. Run `git diff --cached` to compare `HEAD`-vs-index, and then `git diff` to compare index-vs-working-tree. Note that date-and-time stamps on files can matter here too.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` only fetches the remote, while `git pull` fetches the remote and usually tries to merge it.

The merge will fail as there are local changes.

I would guess you would need to share the output of `git status` so that it's possible to see what the changes are.

I few things popping into my head is:

- Having special characters in the filenames, on a machine that doesn't handle them properly, might cause changes to these files.
- Having permission flags set on files, on a machine that doesn't handle them properly, might cause changes to these files.

Comment: I do not think that the problem is related to permissions or filenames (standard english, no special characters). I believe that the problem with permissions would be like empty diff (no changes in content) but that is not my case. Git thinks that current version of repo is several commits back. But current content of files is exactly the same like on Git server.